# How to use the unique function inside a class?

Tags: c++, class, stl

Using inside a class, the BinaryPredicate passed into the unique function should also be a class member function. When I try to pass the in-class member function, an compiling error occurs:

```
cannot convert 'Solution::mycompare' from type 'bool (Solution::)(std::vector<int>, std::vector<int>)' to type 'bool (Solution::*)(std::vector<int>, std::vector<int>)'
```

Below is the source code:

```
class Solution {
public:
    vector<vector<int> > threeSum(vector<int> &num) {
        // Start typing your C/C++ solution below
        // DO NOT write int main() function
        vector<vector<int> > result;
        ...
        unique(result.begin(), result.end(), mycompare);
        return result;
    }

    bool mycompare(vector<int> v1, vector<int> v2) {
        for (int i=0; i<v1.size(); ++i) {
            if (v1[i] != v2[i])
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
};
```

How to resolve this problem? PS: I cannot define a function outside the class.

Comment: Is this for homework? I am curious about the comments "// Start typing your C/C++ solution below // DO NOT write int main() function"

Comment: You might check for equal length of the vectors even before comparing them elementwise.

Comment: @Pedrom , not homework. A problem from an online judge.

Comment: @hetepeperfan , thanks your advise, here I am sure their length are the same.

Answer (score 1):

Declare it as `static`. It doesn't need access to members (`static` or not), so there's no reason why you can't do it.

Also, pass `v1` and `v2` by `const` reference - avoids potential copying.

Comment: Thanks very much for the quick response, @Luchian_Grigore ! Now my program works!

Comment: @Luchian_Grigore , seems that the unique function doesn't work properly. What's the problem with it?

Comment: @injoy you're probably not implementing a strict ordering comparison.

Comment: @injoy you can compare vectors with `==`. That could make the code easier and less error prone.

Comment: @juanchopanza , I changed mycompare function to return v1 == v2; But still, it doesn't work.

Comment: @Luchian Grigore , how to implement a strict ordering comparison?

Comment: @injoy maybe produce some minimal code sample showing how it does not work? You don't need strict weak ordering here.

Comment: The comparator required by unique is an ordering comparator (e.g., std::less), not an equality comparator.  If you'll change the comparator so it returns true if v1 is "less than" v2, and make sure that the input is sorted using the same comparator, the code should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
unique(result.begin(), result.end(), &mycompare);
```

You will be supplying `unique` with the address of your `mycompare` function, which is what it requires.